# Is it possible to have a while loop execute, while some other code runs?

Tags: node.js, while-loop

Is it possible to have a while loop execute, while some other code runs?

For example:

```
    var test = true;

log();

function log() {
    setTimeout(log, 3000);
    test = true;
    console.log("Standard log");
}

while ( test == true ) {
    console.log("Algo");
}
```

If we run the above code, it prints "Standard log" once, then continuously prints "algo". Instead, I'd like it to continuously print "also", alongside printing "standard log" every 3 seconds.

It seems the while loop cancels any other code - I assume this is because its synchronous, but thats a newbie guess.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how best to attack this?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to edit. '''test''' variable should be initialized as false.

Comment: "*I'd like it to continuously print "also", alongside printing "standard log" every 3 seconds.*" use `setInterval`?

Comment: @VLAZ, is this not the same approach as setTimeout(log, 3000); ? If I remove the while loop, the log() function continuously prints "standard log".

Comment: Sort of. Except you don't need to continuously re-queue tasks by calling `setTimeout` recursively - `setInterval` automatically repeats. But more importantly, changing the `while` to an interval allows both pieces of code to execute normally and not take over the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks @VLAZ thats interesting.

Just tested this code and works exactly as expected. Thanks for your help! :) 

`var test = false;

log();

function log() {
    setTimeout(log, 3000);
    test = true;
    console.log("Standard log");
}

setInterval(() => {
    if (test == true) {
        console.log("Algo");
    }
}, 300);`

Answer (score 1):

You have to take the second `while` loop out of the main execution thread, which you can do with `setInterval` with a timer of zero (or anything above that if you want to slow down the loop a bit!).

You'll also need to reverse some of the code there to cancel the interval when `test` becomes false.

```js
var test = true;

log();

function log() {
    setTimeout(log, 3000);
    test = true;
    console.log("Standard log");
}

let intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    if(!test)
       clearInterval(intervalId)
     console.log("Algo");  
},0)
```